# ASP.net File Upload - FileBytes, FileName

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, filenames

Hi I am using a File Upload Control within ASP. i am unable to get File Name or File Bytes within my c# code

aspx

```
 Upload Image: <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fu" /> 
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkContinue" runat="server" class="ButtonGeneric" onCommand="lnkContinue_Click">CLICK</asp:LinkButton>
```

cs Code

```
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 string fileName = fu.FileName;
 int DocumentID = DocumentsComponent.SaveFileByJobID(JobId, UserID, fileName,fu.FileBytes, txtDescription.Text, 1);
}
```

i might have to store the bytes into a byte variable , but i still don't get anything populated within filename string.

update panel in the master page:

```
<div id="content">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" ID="up" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cph" runat="server" /></ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for benefit of other users following this post, as #banana helped me to steer towards the right direction, the problem is with the update panel being used in the master page that i am referencing, removing the update panel will do the job. if i want to keep the update panel i need to use triggers which is beyond the scope of this post.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code with:

```
if(isPostBack)
{
    string fileName = fu.FileName;
    int DocumentID = DocumentsComponent.SaveFileByJobID(JobId, UserID, fileName,fu.FileBytes, txtDescription.Text, 1);
}
```

also check if you are not reloading the file upload control using ajax or on page load, before you submit the file.

Comment: in the pageload method ispostback is included and thie code i posted is within the method that is called from pageload method. so that is handled.

Comment: i would advise putting a breakpoint in page load, and going line by line and checking where file upload loses its content. you might be reloading the control's html before it reaches the block where you read its file content

Comment: updated my question to shoe the button and button click event which contains the code for file upload. i have inserted break, but still cant understand why the file name is not getting populated?

Comment: try wraping your whole content of page_load int `if(!isPostBack)` note the exclamation mark. - its not a solution, its just for testing purposes.

Comment: but this is trigger by the button event rather than page load?

Comment: indeed it is, but page_load executes every time even on post back, before the button click event handler. so if you have on page load code that reloads the file upload, it will reach the button click handler with a new upload control. also note that if you use a master page, the master page's page_load will run prior to your page's.

Comment: #Banana, i have found the problem and it seems it is with the content/master page, if i use content master page the code doesnt work but if i use the html/form in aspx the code does work. Do you know how to get file upload control to work with content/master page?

Comment: Do you have any ajax extension control on the master page? Like an update panel? There shoulndt be any problem with a master page unless there is code in the master page'  page_load that refreshes the file upload

Comment: master mage is referencing few usercontrols and scripts, like model popup and ToolkitScriptManager etc, i have removed the modal popup control but still nothing happens

Comment: Toolkit script manager is an ajax extension, do you jave an update panel?

Comment: yes, please see my updated question for the update panel code within the master page